# 2 Way Friendship between different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, data-modeling

Ruby on Rails App.
I have two kinds of users,

```
Company
  has_many :employees #sample
Employee
  has_one :company
```

I want to create friendships between these two models, keeping track of the requester of the relationship (.requested_relationships) and the receiver (.pending-relationships) as well as the status (accepted, pending, etc). I can easily create the relationship with a third model and has_many :through ... BUT that wouldn't allow me to track who initiated the relationship and thus distinguish between pending and requested relationships. What is the correct way to model this? 
I've been playing around with a polymorphic attribute on the relationship model, but without concrete success.

Comment: I'll also note that this is straightforward enough when there is one User model, like in this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association the key piece here is the addition of a different user type

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use [amistad gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/amistad)

very good for friendship relationship and has a very good documentation that can help you out alot. just check it out

Comment: Thanks for the link, though it looks like that is only for single model friendships. And, I want to do this without a gem.